# Prevent biblatex date output for online citations

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to not print the year (nor a possible author), but only for `Online` types of citations.

Here's an illustration of what I would like to remove (in red):

[image]

Here's my MWE:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}
Example\cite{tab:test}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`mwe.bib`:

```
@Online{tab:test,
  Url                      = {http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg},
  Urldate                  = {2014-02-25},
  Timestamp                = {2014.06.13},
  Note                     = {Table \ref{tab:test}}
}
```

*This question is motivated with difficulties in resolving [Custom biblatex style for citing images and tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184815/custom-biblatex-style-for-citing-images-and-tables), and represents a narrower requirement*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove the date. But note that this code will print only the 'Note', 'URL' and 'URLdate' fields in the bibliography for bib items of type 'online', *even if there are other fields*

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[colorlinks, urlcolor=black]{hyperref} %if you want the link to be clickable

\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents} {mwe.bib}
@online{tab:test,
  author                   = {Doe, John},
  Url                      = {http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg},
  Urldate                  = {2014-02-25},
  Timestamp                = {2014.06.13},
  Note                     = {Table \ref{tab:test}}, %not sure I understand why you are cross-referencing here
  year                     = {2014}, %this is necessary for the in-text citation to work
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, backref=true, style=authoryear, sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%this defines what will be printed in the bibliography for entries of type 'online'
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}%Period+space after 'Note' field
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
Example \citeyear{tab:test} %This lets you cite only the year even if there is an author listed in your bib file, as opposed to \cite

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: This is more than enough for my use case. I now just have to figure out how to resolve the reference.